# react i18next брать перевод из папки компонента

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, i18n, multilanguage

Можно ли настроить `i18next` чтобы переводы хранились не в `public`, а у каждого компонента был свой файл с переводом?
Например такая структра папок и файлов:

```
src
    components
        app-header
            index.tsx
            styled.tsx
            translate.json
        app-footer
            index.tsx
            styled.tsx
            translate.json
        modal
            index.tsx
            styled.tsx
            translate.json
```

В каждом компоненте есть файл `translate.json`, с переводом конкретно для этого компонента

п.с. - компоненты функциональные, не классовые, поэтому в идеале нужен пример хука